# Files written in QEMU guest via VirtIO / 9p belong to user libvirt-qemu

Tags: linux, qemu, libvirt

I have this QEMU virtual machine running Debian Stretch, inside a host also running Debian Stretch. The guest mounts a host directory via VirtIO and 9p:

Virtual Machine Manager, Filesystem settings:

- Mode: Mapped
- Source path: /host/username/Projects
- Target path: host-projects

Mounting on the host works:

`sudo mount -t 9p -o rw,trans=virtio host-projects /guest/username/Projects`

Writing to this directory, however, has proved difficult. I had to

`chgrp -R libvirt-qemu /host/username/Projects`

on the host in order to be able to write to the directory in the guest, but all the files I write inside the guest then belong to not just group but also **user** `libvirt-qemu` on the host.

I want those files to be mine.

How can I configure the **host** ownership? (Short of running `qemu-system-x86_64` under my user id; or having cron `chown -R username.libvirt-qemu /host/username/Projects` every 2 minutes.)

Comment: The sad truth is, 9p lacks an id-mapping facitily. The uids and gids in the guest must match those in the host. I worked around the issue by doing exactly that: creating a user / group combo in the guest that has identical ids to the one I use outside. You also need to specify a more recent protocol revision as a mount option (e. g. ``version=9p2000.L) because the original 9p filesystem didn’t support ownership at all.